# How to handle loaders with multiple ajax requests

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Earlier I used to show a loader before ajax calls start and remove the loader once the call is completed. Now I have two calls in one single page. In this scenario how should I handle the loader ? If I use the same approach as earlier even though other call is not finished loader would be removed

Comment: either localize the loader into its loading components, and have 1 for each event separately or make some boolean flags that switch on while ajax is running (ajaxSend) and off when its finished (onSuccess or ajaxStop). turn on loader with either event, but have a conditional checking to make sure the flags are both off before removing loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular `$q` service which allows to **wait a group of multiple promises to be resolved**.

**Example :**

```
$q.all( [promise1, promise2] ).then(() => {
    // only when both are resolved
    // so here you can remove the loader
});
```